# why does my (centos) docker container not run /etc/bashrc?

Tags: bash, docker

I am creating a docker image in which I would like to mount my home directory. However there is some other `bashrc` file I would like to run upon instantiation.

Trouble is I cannot copy this `bashrc` file into the working directory of my user since that is where I will mount my (host) home directory. I have tried thus appending to `/etc/bashrc` or putting in /etc/profile.d but it never runs.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN adduser -s /bin/bash user -G users
RUN echo "echo /etc/bashrc" >> /etc/bashrc
RUN echo "echo /etc/profile" >> /etc/profile
RUN echo "echo /etc/profile.d/mine.sh" >> /etc/profile.d/mine.sh

USER user
WORKDIR /home/user
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

I now build and run this container while mounting my home directory:

```
docker build -t devenv .
docker run --rm --volume $HOME:/home/user -it devenv
```

When I open the console, only the (mounted) .bashrc runs. However if I run `bash -l` (login shell); then the profile files run (but not .bashrc).

```
bash-4.2$ bash
inside mounted host .bashrc
bash-4.2$ bash -l
/etc/profile.d/mine.sh
/etc/profile
/etc/profile.d/mine.sh
/etc/profile
```

So I don't know where to put my logic that will run when entering the console (and .bashrc should also run)? Why doesn't /etc/bashrc run ever?

***EDIT***: when running `bash` or even `bash -l` in a centos7 virtual machine; /etc/bashrc does get run...

Comment: Right. Login shells (created by the `-l` option) source `.profile`, and non-login shells use `.bashrc`. `/etc/bashrc` isn't really a standard configuration file, requiring (IIRC) a compile time option to be explicitly enabled to source it for non-login interactive shells.

Comment: @chepner do you know any other config file (not residing in the home directory) that I could use?

Comment: I'd suggest sourcing `/etc/bashrc` explicitly at the top of `.bashrc`. It sounds like your VM has some custom `bash` install that enables the use of `/etc/bashrc`, but the Docker image does not.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the hints, these helped me to find a workaround; see my own answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstmost; thanks to @chepner for explaining me why /etc/bashrc doesn't run. So I came up with this nice workaround:

- force bash to load `/etc/bashrc` at startup
- inside `/etc/bashrc`; add my specific configuration and then run `~/.bashrc`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN adduser -s /bin/bash user -G users
# remove /home/user/.bashrc to avoid infinite loop with /etc/bashrc
# when /home/user is not mounted
RUN rm /home/user/.bashrc
RUN echo "if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi" >> /etc/bashrc
RUN echo "echo /etc/bashrc" >> /etc/bashrc
RUN echo "echo /etc/profile" >> /etc/profile
RUN echo "echo /etc/profile.d/mine.sh" >> /etc/profile.d/mine.sh

USER user
WORKDIR /home/user
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "--rcfile", "/etc/bashrc" ]
```

again building and running gives me this output:

```
/etc/profile.d/mine.sh
/etc/bashrc
inside mounted host .bashrc
inside bashrc
```

**CAVEAT**: make sure to remove the original .bashrc in your docker image. The default content in centos:7 of ~/.bashrc is:

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

which creates now an infinite loop if no home directory is mounted.